# Is there any way to route traffic through certain computer located else where?

Tags: networking, windows-8.1, proxy, routing

Here is my problem. I'm currently working at a research organization. They have an institutional subscription to some journals, which provide full access based on IP. Problem is I tend to work not just during officer hours but most of the time at home, while travelling and even while waiting at public transport stations. The major hurdle I'm facing is inability to access journals.

**Is there any software that I can install in my laptop and my desktop in lab?**

I don't have problem leaving that software running all the time. If some how traffic through my laptop is routed through that   Desktop in my lab. I won't have any problem, accessing journals I need.

I'm using Windows 8.1.

Comment: Why down voted?

Answer (score 2):

The proper ways of doing that are:

1. VPN: Just like explained by Keltari, this will enable you not only access your Journal site but also other resources at your working place.
2. Proxy: With a proxy server, you will be able to access your Journals but it will only affect your browsing traffic. Moreover, it can be configured to only use the Journal site via Proxy and the rest of your http traffic will go without Proxy, thus saving bandwidth at your work location if that's an issue, and because you won't actually need that, nor I can think of a reason you'll want to do that.

Otherwise, you can build a ssh tunnel to forward traffic to this Journal site. If you can ssh to a host at work, then you can do something like:

```
ssh me@myhost -L 1234:www.myjournalsite.com:80
```

Then you just need to point your browser to:

```
URL: http://localhost:1234
```

and traffic will be forwarded via ssh to the journal site.
But this option is not a good way of doing it. Either get the VPN or Proxy server. Just get in touch with your Network Administrator.

Answer (score 1):

Check with your organization's IT staff if your organization has a [VPN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_private_network) in place.  A VPN will allow you to connect to your work network and your remote devices will appear as if they are connected to your organizations internal network.  This will allow you to access the journals from anywhere.

Another possibility would be a remote interface to your work computer, such as TeamViewer or VNC.  This would give you remote access to your computers desktop.  This, in turn, would allow you to use your work desktop to access the journals.  This method might not be allowed by your IT policy though.